# Why is 1 == '1,2' true?

Tags: php, types, int, equals

Just curious how PHP type casting work for this case.

```
var_dump(1 == '1,2') // boolean(true)
```

Comment: (It has nothing to do with var_dump, that's only how you're observing the result.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because **1** is an integer here and when it is compared to a string **`1,2`** , this string will be casted to an integer , which returns **1**.

##How does casting a string `1,2` return 1 ?

```
echo int('1,2'); // prints 1
```

So when it is compared to your **1** , this will be obviously returning `true` on your `var_dump`

###From the PHP Docs.. (Basic Comparison Test)

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
> numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
> comparison performed numerically.

[`Source`](https://www.php.net/ternary)

Answer (score 4):

1. It's interpreted as:

   ```
   var_dump(1 === (int) '1,2');
   ```
2. `"1,2"` casted to `int` will return `1`, as anything after last parsed digit is being cutted off (`,2` in this case).
3. Remember that comma (`,`) is not a decimal point separator, dot (`.`) is:

   ```
   var_dump((float) '1,3', (float) '1.3');
   ```

   Results in:

   ```
   (float) 1
   (float) 1.3
   ```

---

Casting can be often very unintuitive, that's why you should almost always use `===` operator, which doesn't create casts.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `==`, php will type cast the right side value to the left side value.
In this case `'1,2'` will be type cast to `1` and return true.

Even `var_dump( 1== "1dfuiekjdfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfasfsadf" );` will return true.